# How polkadot open their slot for auction?

Tags: polkadot, parachain, substrate-parachain-template, relay-chain, auctions

I was make a private network in `relay-chain` and `parachain` and connected `parachain` into relay chain through `sudo` `assign slot pallet` & `slot` locally.
but i want to add my `parachain` into `relay-chain` through auction process and by bid.
Is there any way to add my `parachain` into `relay-chain` locally through auction and also is there anything in polkaodot to open there slot in `relay-chain`
Can anyone explain the process.

Answer (score 1):

Does this answer your question : https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-auction ?

Comment: i just want to know how polkadot open there slot for auction.